# Defining static instance of a class

Tags: c++

I defined a `Vector2` class and thought it would be a good idea to have some predefined members, such as a zero vector or a vector that is pointing to the right.

I created the following method for a zero vector:

```
static inline Vector2 ZERO() {return Vector2(0, 0);}
```

Is it okay to do it this way, or are there any smarter/more efficient ways to do so, like initializing a zero vector as const and only pointing to it?

Comment: You should definitely declare `ZERO` as const (what sense does it make to change it?). Otherwise looks fine.

Comment: If these are really cheap to construct you may just want a `zero()` factory method, or a default constructor that is zeroes.

Comment: Are these vectors mutable or immutable?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the good way.
But the vector2 constructor is defined, it is no need to use static function.
Vector2 vZero = Vector2::ZERO(); // complex,
Vector2 vZero(0,0); // more simple.

If you want more easily,

```
Vector2{ 
public: 
    static const Vector2 ZEROVECTOR = Vector2(0,0);
...}
```

You can use if(vVector == Vector2::ZEROVECTOR) ;// only one emptry vector for every vector2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another idea:

You can define an `enum` for a special initializer to cover some of common instances.

That doesn't require stored constants and just only one additional constructor.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

// initializers for common things
enum Init {
  Init0, // init a 0-vector
  InitX, // init an x unit vector
  InitY // init a y unit vector
};

struct Vector2 {
  double x, y;
  
  Vector2(Init init = Init0):
    x(init == InitX), y(init == InitY)
  { }
  
  Vector2(double x, double y): x(x), y(y) { }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Vector2 &v)
{
  return out << v.x << ", " << v.y;
}

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(Vector2 v0);
  DEBUG(std::cout << v0 << '\n');
  DEBUG(Vector2 v1(Init0));
  DEBUG(std::cout << v1 << '\n');
  DEBUG(Vector2 v2(InitX));
  DEBUG(std::cout << v2 << '\n');
  DEBUG(Vector2 v3(InitY));
  DEBUG(std::cout << v3 << '\n');
  DEBUG(Vector2 v4(1.0, 2.0));
  DEBUG(std::cout << v4 << '\n');
}
```

Output:

```
Vector2 v0;
std::cout << v0 << '\n';
0, 0
Vector2 v1(Init0);
std::cout << v1 << '\n';
0, 0
Vector2 v2(InitX);
std::cout << v2 << '\n';
1, 0
Vector2 v3(InitY);
std::cout << v3 << '\n';
0, 1
Vector2 v4(1.0, 2.0);
std::cout << v4 << '\n';
1, 2
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90ba8585afb5521a)

Please, note that I made `Vector2::Vector2(Init)` *not* `explicit`.

Usually, I prefer to make constructors with only one argument `explicit` to prevent accidental conversions (where I don't expect them). In this case, I would prefer that `InitX` can be used directly where `Vector2` is expected (triggering implicit conversion). That makes this feature even more convenient. (I must admit that I named it e.g. `XAxis` instead of `InitX` in my real code.)